# In redux: every components should get the data only from the store?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

Just something to be clear on redux store, because the others answers and questions in stackoverflow are not give me enough to know the guidelines.

According my understood of redux, In redux applications, Every components should **get the data only from the store**? is it true? for all the cases?

What about those cases?

**Timer**:
In my component I display a counter (counting down for starting a game). so each second the counter is go down. do I have to dispatch an action to down the number in the store, and because the component is subscribed to the store it gets update. This is the right way to keep the use of the redux? I think it running extra script to update my view.

**Autocomplete**:
Should I store the options in the store?

Since all the data need to come from the store, I need to store the autocomplete options from my api to the store. and retrieve the autocomplete options from the store as well.

but it have to be per component because what if I have a multiple the same component with a different data? so I have to do a state looks like this:

```
state = { fooComponent: { autocomplete: [{ key, value }, ... ] } }
```

I ask because it just a temporary data I need to display each time I display those options.

Answer (score 2):

Not all the data should live in the store.

From https://ngrx.io/docs#when-should-i-use-ngrx-for-state-management:

> In particular, you might use NgRx when you build an application with a lot of user interactions and multiple data sources, when managing state in services are no longer sufficient.
>
> A good substance that might answer the question "Do I need NgRx", is the SHARI principle:
>
> Shared: state that is accessed by many components and services.
>
> Hydrated: state that is persisted and rehydrated from external storage.
>
> Available: state that needs to be available when re-entering routes.
>
> Retrieved: state that must be retrieved with a side-effect.
>
> Impacted: state that is impacted by actions from other sources.

Answer (score 0):

It's not even a good practice to store everything in a store. You want to store the "application state" in the store. The state could be "countdown finished" or "countdown in progress" but not the value of seconds. It's going to be an overkill. Countdown value in seconds can be stored perfectly in local state of the countdown component. You want to keep it simple and not to pollute with REDUX action history